# Meaning and usage of "good old"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> Sometimes, some good ol' solitude feels good man.

What does *good old* mean, and how do you usually use it in context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Good old* is whatever is liked or admired or familiar and comforting which

- remains from the past, still functioning as it always did

  > My good old 63 Cutlass
  >   Good old Jimmy Carter
  >   The good old Chicago Democratic machine
- existed or obtained in the past (or you *believe* existed or obtained in the past) -- the "Good old days" -- but is now neglected or vanishing or gone

  > The good old tradition of liberal education
  >   The good old portable typewriter

However, the term is almost always used ironically today:

> Good old Bob, always finds a new way to screw it up.
>   Good old VHS had absolutely unique reds and oranges.
>   The good old Know-Nothing party seems to be making a comeback.

*Good old boy* is a specialized application of the term: a well-regarded and 'connected' man of the politically dominant yeoman class in the US South. This must be distinguished from the British *old boy*, originally an alumnus of one of the prestige 'public' schools, by extension a well-regarded and 'connected' man of the political and financial elite. The two exhibit very different manners and mannerisms.

Comment: My favorite example is from [The Simpsons](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NMxzU6hxrNA): while playing rock-paper-scissors, Bart thinks to himself, *"Good ol' rock.  Nothing beats that!"*

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps use the definition that [FreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/good+old+days) gives, and apply it here.

I use *good old* to mean something that one used to know, and that is no longer seen as much (or at all) in the present time.

The FreeDictionary mentions *good old days - past times remembered with nostalgia*.

[Another entry](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Good+old+days) which is somehow separate:

> back in an earlier time which everyone remembers as a better time, even if it really wasn't. *Back in the good old days, during World War I, they used real cactus needles in record players. The good old days didn't start until they had indoor bathrooms.*

Though [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/the-good-old-days) mentions only the positive part:

> If you talk about the good old days, you mean a time in the past when you believe life was better:
>   *I wish my grandma would stop going on about the good old days.*

In your case, I would interpret *good old solitude* to be like a traditional 'therapy', that none from today can substitute.